# How can I keep background material in place for jewelry photos?

Tags: product-photography, tips, jewelry

I want to make my jewelry photography better by using silk as a background but I want the material to look as if it was loosely thrown as on the picture below.

[image: all credits to FB page: https://www.facebook.com/BELAMILA.jewellery]

The problem is that it keeps bending in different directions.

Are there any good ways to "strengthen" the material so that it stops bending and folding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starch... or strategically placed folds under the heaviest part of the jewel, as in the pic above.